# what's the difference between these two while statements

Tags: java

I am trying to use a while statement in lieu of wait because I personally encounter more trouble using wait.

Back when i exclusively used C++ this sufficed

```
while(!condition){}
```

the condition would either be filled by an 
external thread, an external api 
or if I wanted a timed wait
I would just do something equivalent to

```
double start = System.currentTimeMillis();
while(System.currentTimeMillis() - start < 1000){}
```

This worked fine in c++ but this kind of approach doesn't work in java (at least the ways I've been trying to implement it). The program just sits in stasis even when I know the condition has been filled.

I have however noticed that if I have the while loop run a trivial task it does work

```
JTextArea msgBox = new JTextArea();
while(!condition){
msgBox.append("");
}
```

Does anyone know why adding just a small trivial task makes such a big difference? I believe that understanding this will help better elucidate what exactly is happening in a while loop for us beginner programmers.

Comment: I think you need to go read the [java docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#currentTimeMillis()) for `System.currentTimeMillis()`. It doesn't do what I think you expect it should. If you are a beginner programmer the last thing you should be doing is making assumptions on how things work

Comment: This is a horrible way of waiting. It basically puts the CPU at 100% usage until some other thread changes the condition. Learn proper use of multithreading. And read about the visibility guarantees that the Java memory model offers, or not, based on the way you synchronize or not.

Comment: I don't think that is an appropriate duplicate, Jarrod. I voted to close as a typographical error because it's not useful to any future readers (he just didn't know what `System.currentTimeMillis()` did).

Comment: I don't think the question is even asking about System.currentTimeMillis(). It says he could do a wait similar to that loop, which is perfectly valid but not very good. The question is about why the loop is an infinite loop without a small wait. Which is answered by James Large's answer.

Comment: Agreed, the System.currentTitmeMillis() is totally a red herring.  The real question was, why did the call to msgBox.append() change the behavior.

Comment: watch check this out
double start = System.currentTimeMillis();

while(System.currentTimeMillis() - start < 1000){}

Sorry i took a short cut in originally writing it, really didnt think it was a big deal. James is the only one who actually tried helping me and i appreciate that

Comment: Not to mention this question is in no way a duplicate to the question you linked to..

Comment: @JBNizet Horrible?  Maybe, maybe not.  It depends what you're waiting for, on the platform, etc.  The C code that I work in has several examples of busy waiting, and we have benchmarks that show a definite performance benefit vs. using a mutex.  In our case, the critical section is very small (three or four native instructions), the contention is light, and we know that it will only ever run on big, multi-processor servers.  The chance of one thread being caught in the loop while another thread that owns the lock waits in the run queue is practically zero.

Comment: @jameslarge: the justification of this technique (*because I personally encounter more trouble using wait*) makes me think that the OP doesn't understand the implications of such a busy loop. I might be wrong, but I doubt it. Waiting in the EDT is already a design problem in itself: it freezes the GUI.

Comment: @JB Nizet - wait is NOT an option for my particular scenario. I am talking to a server through an Api provided. the Api uses a handler to populated variables in arrayLists. the condition was checking to see if the arrayList is empty. I can't do a timed wait either because the Api's response time fluctuates wildly and because the program's efficacy  is dramatically effected by timing, wasted time by having too long a wait, even by a few 100 millis is too not acceptable. I have also considered trying to rig the backend Api to suite me but as it has many moving parts, this is not an issue either

Comment: I'm not an idiot, I was just trying to be concise and wanted a concise answer, most people were caught up on the System.currentTimeMillis to even try helping me. As you can see from my edit above, and my comment, I know what that function does and know how to use it appropriately. as stated, I am not an idiot, I wrote in short hand with the assumption you people would have enough imagination to know what i'm talking about. Obviously not.

Comment: Out of all these responses, only one person actually wanted to help me, and it shows. Just imagine how useful this site would be if it was full of people who actually wanted to help... sorry for the rant

Comment: Waiting or busy looping in the event disptach thread will freeze your GUI. You should NOT wait, and you should not busy-loop either. What you should do is use a SwingWorker (or any similar construct) that would invoke a method in the EDT once the background thread doing the long server call has received the response. I don't see why you think that a solution based on a wait would take more than 100ms. to wake up the waiting thread, and I don't see how consuming 100% CPU for a long time would make your app faster.

Comment: Thank you for your constructive response. I will look up SwingWorker and see if that is what I'm looking for.
as for the wait, the problem would be if its 100ms more then what it need to be. or if the wait is for 1000ms and then it turns out the condition isnt met until 1001ms in which case i would waste a full 999ms 

the msgBox.append halts the loop the moment the condition is met.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is `condition` a volatile variable?  If not, then when thread A updates the variable, the Java Language Specification makes no guarantee about how much time will elapse before thread B sees the change.  On some architectures, it could take forever.

When you call msgBox.append(""), that quite likely invokes Java synchronization primitives that could make a prior update to `condition` become visible to the calling thread.

Answer (score 4):

`System.currentTimeMillis()` [returns the time since Jan 1, 1970 UTC](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#currentTimeMillis()), which is never* < 1000

*Assumes your system time is correct